# Making list of sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have copied a code to generate a list of sheets in new sheet.
I also have a hidden sheet named "Ukryte" which i would not like to have in list of sheets.
How exactly can i skip this sheet or all hidden sheets in this loop.

Here is the loop;

```
'Create Array list with sheet names (excluding Contents)
ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1)

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If sht.Name <> ContentName Then
myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
x = x + 1
End If
Next sht
```

Here is full code for SUB

```
Sub Spis_Treści()

'PURPOSE: Add a Table of Contents worksheets to easily navigate to any tab
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim Content_sht As Worksheet
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim shtName1 As String, shtName2 As String
Dim ContentName As String

'Inputs
  ContentName = "Spis Treści"
  
'Optimize Code
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Delete Contents Sheet if it already exists
  On Error Resume Next
    Worksheets("Spis Treści").Activate
  On Error GoTo 0

  If ActiveSheet.Name = "Spis Treści" Then
    myAnswer = MsgBox("Czy chcesz zaktualizować Spis Treści?", vbYesNo)
    
    'Did user select No or Cancel?
      If myAnswer <> vbYes Then GoTo ExitSub
      
    'Delete old Contents Tab
      Worksheets("Spis Treści").Delete
  End If

'Create New Contents Sheet
  Worksheets.Add Before:=Worksheets(1)

'Set variable to Contents Sheet
  Set Content_sht = ActiveSheet

'Format Contents Sheet
  With Content_sht
    .Name = ContentName
    .Range("B1") = "Numery zleceń"
    .Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
  End With

'Create Array list with sheet names (excluding Contents)
  ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 1)

  For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sht.Name = ContentName Then
   
    Else
      myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht
  
'Alphabetize Sheet Names in Array List
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    For y = x To UBound(myArray)
      If UCase(myArray(y)) < UCase(myArray(x)) Then
        shtName1 = myArray(x)
        shtName2 = myArray(y)
        myArray(x) = shtName2
        myArray(y) = shtName1
      End If
     Next y
  Next x

'Create Table of Contents
  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)
    Set sht = Worksheets(myArray(x))
    sht.Activate
    With Content_sht
      .Hyperlinks.Add .Cells(x + 2, 3), "", _
      SubAddress:="'" & sht.Name & "'!A1", _
      TextToDisplay:=sht.Name
      .Cells(x + 2, 2).Value = x
    End With
  Next x
  
Content_sht.Activate
Content_sht.Columns(3).EntireColumn.AutoFit

'A Splash of Guru Formatting! [Optional]
  Columns("A:B").ColumnWidth = 3.86
  Range("B1").Font.Size = 18
  Range("B1:F1").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlThin
  
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Range("C2").Activate
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    End With
    Range("B1:F1").Merge
  With Range("B1:F1")
  .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
  .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
 End With
 
  With Range("B3:B" & x + 1)
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = xlMedium
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .Interior.Color = RGB(91, 155, 213)
End With

  'Adjust Zoom and Remove Gridlines
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = 130

ExitSub:
'Optimize Code
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

I tried using
1.

```
    If sht.Name <> ContentName Or sht.Name <> "Ukryte" Then
      myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht
```

2. 

```
If sht.Name = ContentName or sht.Name = "Ukryte" Then

Else
  myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht
```

3. 

```
If sht.Name = ContentName Then
ElseIf sht.Name = "Ukryte" Then
Else 
  myArray(x + 1) = sht.Name
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Next sht
```

I always seem to get error: Subscript out of range
Either in the loop itself or in 'Create Table of Content

Comment: Only include sheet in array if it is visible: `If sht.Visible = True Then`

Comment: You are skipping 2 worksheets (`Spis Treści` and `Ukryte`) so it has to be `ReDim myArray(1 To Worksheets.Count - 2)` and any of your tries. When you would get the error, after selecting `Debug`, the line `Set sht = Worksheets(myArray(x))` would have been highlighted in yellow. You just could have hovered over `myArray(x)` when you would have seen that its value is `""` which cannot be a sheet name.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify the line `If sht.Name = ContentName Then` to `If sht.Name = ContentName Or sht.Visible = False Then`.